# Filtering non-json content in a json stream in Go

Tags: json, go

I'm working with an input stream of json structures in Go. I receive the input stream from another application on my stdin and I can't alter the communications protocol.

The problem I have is that every json structure is terminated by a non-json string line: "end" (without the quotes).

I'm using the Golang encoder/json package to decode the json I'm receiving from stdin. The problem is that the decoder produces an error the second time I call it with the msg: "invalid character 'e' looking for beginning of value".

The issue, of course is, that the "end" string is not json encoded. I would like to know how I can have Go's json decoder skip over this string?

Some sample input:

```
{"command": "ack", "id": "1231231"}
end
{"command": "fail", "id": "1231231"}
end
{
    "command": "log",
    // the message to log
    "msg": "hello world!"
}
end
```

Things I've tried:

- I declared: endStr := make([]byte, 10)
- I've tried to use fmt.Fscanf(os.Stdin, "%s", endStr), to read past the string, but no data are read.
- I've tried to use os.Stdin.Read(endStr), but it also returns no data.
- After I read the first json structure, dec.Buffered() returns an io.Reader containing the "end" string, but I don't know how to tell the decoder to skip over this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First: JSON decoding works _only_ for valid JSON input so you _must_ split your input stream at these "end" markers before decoding each chunk.

Comment: First: Show full code and realistic sample input. Second: JSON decoding works _only_ for valid JSON input so you _must_ split your input stream at these "end" markers before decoding each chunk. Depending on your actual input data you could try http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner with a custom Split function which splits at your "end" markers. Again: If possible provide demo input on play.golang.org (Hit Return too fast...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the best solution I've been able to come up with is:

1. Ditch the json Decoders,
2. read a byte slice from stdin,
3. trim the slice to exclude the ("\nend\n") character string
4. pass the trimmed slice to a json Unmarshaller

The code I had to write:

```
// Create a buffer to hold the stream data
data := make([]byte, 5000)

// Read data from stdin in a loop
for {
    _, err = os.Stdin.Read(data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    index := bytes.Index(data, []byte("\n"))
    data = data[:index]

    var myStruct MyStruct
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &myStruct)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //(Do something with myStruct)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is messy, but it will do the trick:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"
import "bytes"
import "io"
import "bufio"

var input = `{"command": "ack", "id": "1231231"}
end
{"command": "fail", "id": "1231231"}
end
`

func main() {
    // make an io.Reader out of our input constant
    var input = bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(input))
    // we're going to need a buffered reader so we can Peek
    var buf = bufio.NewReader(input)

    // This is the result of the decode.  Use whatever makes sense for you
    var res map[string]interface{}
    var err error
    var dec *json.Decoder
    // We're going to loop until we get an error (hopefully it will be io.EOF
    for err == nil {
        if dec != nil {
            // This is the tricky bit:  json.Decoder has its own buffer.
            // it will read more than the data it needs.  In my simple test, 
            // it buffers all of the data.  What we're doing here is constructing
            // a new bufio.Reader using the remaining bytes in the json decoder's buffer
            // and whatever hasn't been read from our original buffer.
            buf = bufio.NewReader(io.MultiReader(dec.Buffered(), buf))
        }
        // Now let's try to drop an 'end' statement from the buffer
        dropEnd(buf)
        // We need a new json.Decoder each time since the old one contains unusable
        // data in its internal buffer.
        dec = json.NewDecoder(buf)
        // do the decode
        if err = dec.Decode(&res); err == nil {
            fmt.Println("Read:", res)
        }
    }
    if err != io.EOF {
        fmt.Println("Unexpected error:", err)
    }
}

func dropEnd(buf *bufio.Reader) {
    var check = make([]byte, 4)
    // If the next 4 bytes (either "\nend" or "end\n") contain "end", drop read them off the buffer
    if check, _ = buf.Peek(4); bytes.Contains(check, []byte("end")) {
        buf.Read(check)
    }
}
```

You can play with this code here: http://play.golang.org/p/7NER_fTzXI

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `os.Stdin` in [bufio.Reader](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader) from the `bufio` package. Then use [buf.Peek(num)](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.Peek) to look ahead before you Decode.

You can also use a custom [Scanner](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) to delimit the JSON chunks.

What's nice about using `bufio` vs a static buffer is it'll work on a stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you can restrict your JSON objects to a single line, you just have to break the input by line and ignore what doesn't Unmarshal. Here's a small piece of code.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

var input = `{"command": "ack", "id": "1231231"}
end
{"command": "fail", "id": "1231231"}
end
`

type Obj struct {
    Command string
    Msg     string
    Id      string
}

func DoSomethingCool(o Obj) {
    // Do something cool here
    fmt.Println(o)
}

func main() {
    inputs := strings.Split(input, "\n")
    for _, v := range inputs {
        var obj Obj
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(v), &obj); err == nil {
            DoSomethingCool(obj) // Got a valid JSON
        }
    }
}
```